# How to identify system shared libraries?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library, software-distribution

My software tool has some external dependencies. I am distributing it as a [conda](https://conda.io/docs/index.html) package for linux64 with precompiled dependencies including shared libraries. Unfortunately I don't know how to recognize the system libraries from the software-specific ones. I think distributing libs like `libc` is not necessary and even should be avoided, because different Linux distros can have specific versions of some system libs.

I am using this simple oneliner to export shared libs ([source](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10238/copy-all-shared-libraries-for-a-binary-to-directory)):

```
$ ldd file | grep "=> /" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' cp -v '{}' /destination
```

For example, these are the shared libs for Tesseract software:

```
$ ldd tesseract.bin 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff4bc7000)
libtesseract.so.4 => not found
liblept.so.5 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0ad8bf3000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0ad89dc000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0ad8615000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0ad830a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000563cf6115000)
```

As you can see, only `libtesseract.so.4` and `liblept.so.5` are software-specific libs (not found because they aren't in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`).

**So is there any way to recognize the system shared libraries?** I can check if they are in `/lib`, but is this always true? Are there only system libs so they can't be somewhere else?

Comment: Why don't you link this statically?

Comment: `/lib` depends on how exotic the Linux is; NixOS for example has no `/lib` (nor `/lib64`) directory. You could try asking the ports or package system, I guess, to see if something belongs to a known port or package...

Comment: @rudimeier That's the best solution, but unfortunately it's very complicated (even impossible) in case of some libs. I have tried that.

Comment: @thrig My distro is Ubuntu which si following the File System Hierarchy Standard. But according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/17546/599219) `/lib` contains libs needed for boot and for binaries in `/bin`. So I think not all the system libs are there. On the other hand if I filter libs located there, I should filter most of the system libs and the rest can be checked manually.